# Set charset only to part of html

Tags: html, character-encoding

I have html widget that loads on other people's websites where default encoding can be other than UTF-8. How can I ensure that my widget will be rendered as UTF-8 (It's not an Iframe)? Can I set charset only to my "div block"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The charset is set for the entire file (although the charset assumption may be wrong).

So, if someone includes your snippet into their page, they have to make sure the charsets match. Otherwise you might deliver an array, maybe JSON, so they can handle the encoding on their side.